# Rails 5.2.1 association issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm facing joins association issue in Rails 5.2.1, below query working properly in rails 5.2.0 but not in 5.2.1

```
User.joins(:roles).where(email: 'test@gmail.com', roles: {titles: ['test1', 'test2']})
```

Here relation between user and roles had has_many, following error I'm getting while running this query in rails console.

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

from /Users/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency/join_association.rb:12:in `initialize'

Comment: That code, in isolation, should work fine in both rails versions. There must be something else that causes the error. Can you show us the *full* stack trace, not just the last line?

Comment: My guess (given the lack of information) is that you're using an older version of `ransack`; support for rails 5.2.1 was added in [this PR](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/pull/938) -- you need to update the gem.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom Lord. yeah, after updating my ransack gem version 1.8.8 to 2.0.1 it's working.